# Nested ActionBar in android?

Tags: android, nested, android-actionbar

Is there a way to do nested `ActionBar` in Android?

What I mean is that..

when I press one of the `tab buttons` in the tab menu, I want to show another `sub-menu tabs` below the main-menu

Is that possible ? If you can provide me with examples, please..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
import com.example.android.supportv4.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;

public class FragmentTabs extends FragmentActivity 
{
  private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_tabs);
        mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        mTabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.realtabcontent);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
                FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
                LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Custom"),
                LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Throttle"),
                LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class, null);
    }
}
```

This can also be used inside of a fragment through fragment nesting:

```
import com.example.android.supportv4.R;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class FragmentTabsFragmentSupport extends Fragment {
    private FragmentTabHost mTabHost;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        mTabHost = new FragmentTabHost(getActivity());
        mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.fragment1);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("simple").setIndicator("Simple"),
                FragmentStackSupport.CountingFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("contacts").setIndicator("Contacts"),
                LoaderCursorSupport.CursorLoaderListFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("custom").setIndicator("Custom"),
                LoaderCustomSupport.AppListFragment.class, null);
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("throttle").setIndicator("Throttle"),
                LoaderThrottleSupport.ThrottledLoaderListFragment.class, null);

        return mTabHost;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        mTabHost = null;
    }}
```

For more details please refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTabHost.html